# Eager Loading from nested partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading, partials

The gem bullet is saying that I have an N + 1 error when loading meal_foods for each meal food that's loaded to the page. Let me explain...

In my rails app I have some nested partials being rendered like so:

Meals > Meal Foods..

So multiple meals are rendered, and then for each meal that is rendered, it's corresponding meal food(s) are rendered within it as well, if any.

Here's the code for that.

Within meal/show:

```
<% if @meals != nil %>
   <%= render(partial: "meal", collection: @meals) %>
<% else %>
   <p style="text-align:center">No meals created yet.</p>
<% end %>
```

Here is within the _meals.html.erb

```
<tbody>
  <%= render(partial: "meal_foods/meal_food", collection: meal.meal_foods) %>
</tbody>
```

Finally this is part of the _meal_foods.html.erb

```
<td class="left"><%= meal_food.name %></td>
<td class="left">
  <%= form_for meal_food, action: :update do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :servings %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Meals Controller:

```
def show
  @meals      = current_client.meals    
  @new_meal   = current_client.meals.build
end
```

The specific error:

```
N+1 Query detected
  Meal => [:meal_foods]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:meal_foods]
N+1 Query method call stack
/app/views/meals/_meal.html.erb:23:in
```

The line this error is pointing to is the render line for the _meal.html.erb partial..

The funny thing is that if I include earger loading in that partial bullet gives me the error "Unused eager loading!" and also the meal foods in the first food are carried over to the rest of the meals incorrectly.

This method looks like this:

Within the _meal.html.erb...

```
<tbody>
  <% mf = MealFood.includes(:meal) %>
  <%= render(partial: "meal_foods/meal_food", collection: mf) %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Change your `@meals` variable to be `current_client.meals.includes(:meal_food)`

Comment: it worked because the `@meals` without `.includes(:meal_food)` run `1` query to get the meals... and in every partial (this line specifically `meal.meal_foods`) it run **1 query for every meal you have**... so if you have `n` meals you run `1` query to get all the meals and `n` queries to get each meal.meal_food (`n+1`)... if you use the `includes(:meal_food)` **it runs only one optimized query to get the meals with their meal food relation loaded**... please wait for @CWitty to write the answer and mark it :D

Comment: Ohhh.. it retrieves each meal AND their corrosponding meal foods in one query? Very cool. Also, why was my comment deleted? CWitty deserves the credit for answering first. I guess whoever writes official answers my question with this info will just get credit.

Comment: No @CWitty is the one who deserves the credit

Comment: Ill add it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `@meals` variable to be `current_client.meals.includes(:meal_food)`. As @artimees said this eager loads the data and prevents an n+1 query. It worked because the @meals without .includes(:meal_food) run 1 query to get the meals... and in every partial (this line specifically meal.meal_foods) it run 1 query for every meal you have... so if you have n meals you run 1 query to get all the meals and n queries to get each meal.meal_food (n+1)... if you use the includes(:meal_food) it runs only one optimized query to get the meals with their meal food relation loaded...

Comment: Dude come on... Copy the explanation and get the rep. You deserve it.